# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: input.dispatchEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, set

I'm writing a code for an chrome extension, where I want to change the field value for facebook marketplace.

```
function changeValue(el, value) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        const input = el;
        if (!input) {
            return;
        }

        const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;  // change value to files
        nativeInputValueSetter.call.bind(input, value);

        const ev2 = new Event('input', {
            bubbles: true
        });
        input.dispatchEvent(ev2);

        input.value = value;
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        resolve();
    });
}
```

When I'm using this block in the console of the webpage, it's successfully changing the value. But when I used this function in the extension it gave me "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: input.dispatchEvent is not a function" in the "input.dispatchEvent" part of the code , I'm not understanding if it is a permission issue or a version issue. The given arguments: el is the field that I want to change and value is the new value I want to set.

Comment: I changed it to nativeInputValueSetter.call.bind(input, value); which solved the previous error. But it is now showing "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: input.dispatchEvent is not a function" which generated from the input.dispatchEvent(ev2); line.

Comment: You should change the body, not the comment.

Comment: If you don't use MAIN world, there's no need for nativeInputValueSetter and you can simply do `input.value = value`.